# Magento 1.9 - Maximum file upload size?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, image-upload

I have to upload photos that are about 5-10mb each,but the default maximum size is 2mb.
I've searched in google and found that you have to edit the php.ini file and increase the amount.
However, when I go into my Cpanel, I cannot find php.ini, but there is phpsample.ini
If I go into this phpsample.ini, there is no code that has the maximum file size.
is there any other solution to fix this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: ask your host, they will do for you or will tell you where to access php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your php settings for the values set.

You can create phpInfo.php and paste the below code in it

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

This will give you full info of your settings. You can check the values for

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 2M
```

You can increase this values and restart your server. To know which php file you are using look for the below detail

**Loaded Configuration File**   `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

If you are using shared hosting you need to contact your server administrator.

You can also try adding this code in your script file

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '5M');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update `php.ini` settings:

memory_limit = 32M

upload_max_filesize = 24M

post_max_size = 32M

And don’t forget to restart your server afterwards.

Hope this will work!!